# How to populate data from backend in dropdownlist and select the value in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, observable

I hava Angular 8 application and I am using material.

What I want to archieve is that data from the backend will be populated in a dropdownlist.

The code of the api call looks like this:

```
returnQrCodes$ : Observable<QRCodeDefinitionSelectOptionApi[]>;
```

api call:

```
getQrCodes(){
this.returnQrCodes$ =    this.qrDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })

  }
```

and the template looks like this:

```
  <div
      class="search-select searchoptions" *ngIf="selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
      <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)] = "selectedValueOptie"  >
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of returnQrCodes$ | async " [value]="option.value" >
          {{ option.qrCode }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </div>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<QRCodeDefinitionSelectOptionApi[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2740)
```

on this line:

```
this.returnQrCodes$
```

Thank you

So I have a other api call who filters the values:

like this:

```
 filterByQrCodes() {
    this.participantService
      .filterParticipantsByQRCode(1, this.selectedValue as any , moment(this.startDate).format('YYYY MM D'), 'testQrJoost176')
      .subscribe(filterByQrcode => {
        console.log(filterByQrcode);
        console.log(this.selectedValue as any);
      });
  }
```

So the dropdown values from the backend has to filtered with this api call

So how now use this api call:

```
  getQrCodes(){
    this.returnQrCodes$ = this.qrDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection().pipe(
        tap(console.log)
    )
}
```

with this hard coded value: `testQrJoost176` so that a user can select a value from the dropdownlist

Comment: don't subscribe and use async pipe. the async pipe subscribes (and unsubscribes) behind the scenes

Comment: I try it like this:   getQrCodes(){
this.returnQrCodes$ =    this.qrDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection().pipe(map( result => {
      console.log(result);
    }));

  }

Comment: But still get error

Comment: map *changes* the result to `Observable<void>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
getQrCodes(){
    this.returnQrCodes$ = this.qrDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection()
}
```

if you need to console.log also use (side effect):

```
getQrCodes(){
    this.returnQrCodes$ = this.qrDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection().pipe(
        tap(console.log)
    )
}
```

Comment: Ah, oke, I get the returned opties back from the backend in the dropdown. But If I select one. the the value is not selected

Comment: please update question, but hazarding a guess your backend return does not have a value field - this would be a good use of map.

Comment: But the problem is also if I only push a button then the list will be populated. But if I trigger the dropdownlist nothing happens

Comment: ah, this is doing the trick: value="option.value".So without []